# Adding string/value to logging format

Tags: python-3.x, logging

In my service, I am adding `f'Request_id={self.request_id}` at the beginning of all the logs in the classes that have `self.request_id`

I am wondering if there's a way to automatically add this information so I don't forget to add it when coding.

My current overall log settings are (set in main.py):

```
basicConfig(format="%(levelname)s: %(message)s")
logger = getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel('INFO')
```

Is there a way I can achieve it by conditionally setting

```
if self.request_id` in the scode
    add Request_id={self.request_id} to the log
```

env:

- python 3.6
- fastapi 0.83.0
- logging came with python

Thanks!

Comment: How are "the classes that have self.request_id" calling the logger?

Comment: @Botje Simply `logger.info(f'Request_id={self.request_id}: <actually logs...>')` with `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` on the top